# How to set data of MPAndroidChart LineChart with an ArrayList of Ints?

Tags: java, mpandroidchart

I have an ArrayList of ints that I would like to use in my MPAndroidChart LineChart. However, I am new to Java and don't know how to convert it to the required "Entry" data type. Can you help me?

I tried the following:

```
ArrayList<int[]> data2line= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data));

LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(data2line,"Data Set 1");
ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(lineDataSet1);

LineData dataLine = new LineData(dataSets);
lineChart.setData(dataLine);
```

Comment: you are using an ArrayList of int arrays, not ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array of entries, something like this:

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new Entry(1, 50));
entries.add(new Entry(2, 100));
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I have a lot of data (+10,000 ints), and was wondering if I could avoid using a loop to add entries like you proposed to save performance. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: how do you store your data?

Comment: I use a module called Chaquopy to transfer data from a Python Numpy.array to Java and recieve it like this: 

int[] data2 = py.getModule("main").callAttr("rula_timeline").toJava(int[].class);

It should be a list like {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7}.

I also tried with:

short[] data2 = py.getModule("main").callAttr("rula_timeline").toJava(short[].class);

Comment: and how do you want to display each value of the data2 array? the Entry class requires 2 parameters, one for the x value, one for the y value

Comment: I only want to display the y-values. X-values should just follow each y-value like 0,1,2,3...

Comment: then simply use a for loop: `for (int i = 0; i < data2.size; i++) { entries.add(new Entry(i, data2[i])); }`